# Find $m$ (approx) maximally distant unit vectors in a unit $n$-sphere, where $m > n$

Tags: geometry, optimization, vectors, spheres, packing-problem

I want to find $m$ unit vectors on the surface of a $n$-sphere, where $m > n$ and the cosine angle amongst the $m$ vectors is maximal. There are a few posts on this particular problem ([ref 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere), [ref 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079146/calculating-a-spread-of-m-vectors-in-an-n-dimensional-space), [ref 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274173/maximum-equal-angle-separation-between-n-unit-vectors-in-d-dimensional-euc), [ref 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663014/is-this-really-an-open-problem-maximizing-angle-between-n-vectors), [ref 5](http://neilsloane.com/packings/)), and it seems to be a well-studied problem. But, I am interested in only an approximate solution to the problem. I believe the Thompson problem and the Tammes problem are the closest problems with a formal definition to my problem but for a 2-sphere. I found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0535.pdf) that suggests an iterative algorithm to my problem. Is there a better and faster approach, possibility with a publicly available implementation? Also, is there a formal definition/problem name for this other than saying that it is a generalization of the Tammes problem?